# MacBook Air (2013) internal keyboard and trackpad not working

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, trackpad

I have MacBook Air mid-2013 and this is my problem:

In Linux and Windows keyboard and touchpad works normally.
But in macOS, they are not working (only the power button is working)